# Asynctask wait function causes error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, udp

im trying to run this code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    InetAddress client = null;
    boolean run = true;
    String data = "";
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    while( run )
    {
        if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "" ) )
        {

        }

        //Send some data
        if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "connect" ) )
        {

        }






        //Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + data);

        try 
        {
            this.wait( 25 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with trying to sleep");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Error with while run value");
    return "finished";
}
```

and once it reachs the this.wait( 25 ); I get this error

```
04-02 18:49:25.070: D/gameObject(9065): New game object
04-02 18:49:25.085: W/dalvikvm(9065): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at com.example.gelorph_v1.gameServer.doInBackground(gameServer.java:116)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at com.example.gelorph_v1.gameServer.doInBackground(gameServer.java:1)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-02 18:49:25.089: E/AndroidRuntime(9065):     ... 4 more
```

Any reason why this is happening?

Canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `wait` is what you want. This tells it to wait to be notified by another `thread` through calling `notify()`. Try

`Thread.sleep(25);`  // 25 is time in millis to sleep

instead. This will make the `thread` sleep (obviously) for the amount of time you have declared before proceeding

[Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

[Wait](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29)

Comment: Sure can, I do it all the time. Its a background `Thread` so it doesn't hurt anything. You don't want to call it on a `UI` thread but `AsyncTask` is just fine. Give it a try

Comment: I do apologize, my application is now complete, and yes it did work, but i removed it because of a lag issue, but you did answer correctly :)

Comment: No apologies necessary, I just wanted to see if this took care of your problem. I'm glad you got it working but if you need it in there then please post the issues with the lag and maybe we can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to wait and not sleep?  If you want it to always pause for 25 ms, use sleep.  If you do want to use wait, you need to do so in a synchronized block for the object you're waiting on.